# Get Amazon AWS's services availability %

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

e.g. Amazon DynamoDB SLA is 99.999%

Can I get particular information such as what are the % in the last 3 years?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any APIs that support retrieving SLAs. Each service reports its own SLAs independently. If you want the historical SLAs then you might have to use wayback machine.

FYI DynamoDB advertises 99.999% SLA for Global Tables or 99.99% otherwise. Also, DynamoDB documents its [current SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/sla/) and [previous SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/sla/historical/).